# Cosmos SDK: couldn't verify signature: unable to verify single signer signature

Tags: blockchain, signature, cosmos-sdk

I’m getting this error when trying to multisign a tx. The 3 signers sent their signed json but when trying to combine them I get:

```
Error: couldn't verify signature: unable to verify single signer signature
```

I’ve read that it’s most likely chain ID or sequence. I’m pretty sure chainID is correct but don’t know how to verify the sequence nor what it means. How can a tx have the wrong sequence number ?

Maybe a noob question … but that’s exactly what I am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was surprisingly easy which is not surprising given the lack of documentation . I was trying to multisign a tx and one of the signers was using the wrong ledger to sign his transaction.
Believe it or not but you can specify which signer from the key ring will sign, then take the wrong ledger and sign. You won’t get an error message.